# How to use other Singleton from within builder.Services.Configure() in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm building a .NET 7 MVC app that uses Azure AD for Authentication but calls out to another API to add additional claims to the Identity.

This worked great when I defined the Claim Transformation statically, but I'd like to register the Claim Transformation as a singleton instead so that it can manage its own token lifetime to the API.

This is what the code looked like to add the claims when the transformation was static:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
builder.Services.Configure<MicrosoftIdentityOptions>(
OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, opt =>
{
opt.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
{
if (context.Principal != null)

                {
                    
                    context.Principal = await ClaimsAPI.TransformAsync(context.Principal);
                }
            };
    
        });
```

This works, but the Claim Transformation class can't store a bearer jwt, and would need to get a fresh one every time, wasting a ton of resources.

this is the closest I've come to getting it to work as a singleton, but it causes plenty of issues

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICLaimsAPI, ClaimsAPI>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
builder.Services.Configure<MicrosoftIdentityOptions>(
        OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, opt =>
        {
            opt.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
            {
                if (context.Principal != null)

                {
                    context.Principal = await builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider()
                                               .GetRequiredService<IClaimsAPI>()
                                               .TransformAsync(context.Principal);
                   
                }
            };

        });
```

This generates a seperate copy of each singleton, which doesn't really work for obvious reasons.
How can I inject my service so that it adds the claims correctly?

EDIT: Solved!

I had to do some slight tweaks to @Acegambit's code. here is my working solution for postierity, just in case someone in the future needs to solve a similar problem.

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IClaimsAPI, ClaimsAPI>();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
builder.Services.AddOptions().AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<MicrosoftIdentityOptions>>(provider =>
        {
            var ClaimsAPI = provider.GetRequiredService<IClaimsAPI>();
            return new ConfigureNamedOptions<MicrosoftIdentityOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, opt =>
                    {
                        opt.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                        {
                            if (context.Principal != null)

                            {
                                context.Principal = await ClaimsAPI.TransformAsync(context.Principal);
                            }
                        };

                    });
        });
```

Comment: If you register an IClaimsTransformation, it should get called automagically per request. What am I missing?

Comment: If I register an `IClaimsTransforation`, then it will do the claims tranform on each request, so I'd be querying the API every time someone clicks a link or goes to another page.

by adding it to `OnTokenValidated`, I add the claims on login, and they're saved in the token in the cookie. only one API call per login, significantly less resources, and faster for the user

Comment: So, you want to cache all of the state into the token on creation, I understand. That has 2 downsides: 
Permission changes will not be observed until the token expires. It's a security risk, but you need to decide if that's a problem for your application.

The token will get bigger. Each request is paying for a bigger token because there's more stuff in it to avoid the DB call per request.

The other alternative is caching.

Comment: Those are both trade-offs of doing it at login. In my case I believe they are worth it in my case because:
1. This is an internal business application, and the permissions are assigned via job title which don't change frequently.
2. the token is still pretty small. There shouldn't need to be a huge number of claims added. probably less than 10 for most applications.

If you were working in an environment where this was accessible to the public, or permissions changed frequently, registering an `ICLaimsTransformation` and checking the API at each request would probably be worth it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took a little digging into the IServiceCollection extension methods.  Looking at the implementation of `Configure<TOptions>` it really doesn't do a whole lot other than call `.AddOptions()` and register a singleton of type `IConfigureOptions` so I think you can pull out that code and do it yourself like so:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IClaimsAPI, ClaimsAPI>();
builder.Services.AddOptions();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<MicrosoftIdentityOptions>>(provider =>
{
    var claimsApi = provider.GetRequiredService<IClaimsAPI>();
    return new ConfigureNamedOptions<MicrosoftIdentityOptions>(string.Empty, options =>
    {
      // TODO: insert your logic to set the context.Principle here
      //        using the claimsApi that should resolve from the provider above
    });
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! This is exactly what I needed. I'm still not entirely sure how IConfigureOptions works, or what it does, but this is perfect.

I made some some slight adjustments to the code provided. I'll add it to my question on top for posterity in case  someone in the future has a similar problem.

I guess that I need to do some reading on how IConfigureOptions works with DI.

Answer (score 2):

There's already an answer but I figure it would be good to show how options has evolved to make this scenario a bit more terse:

```
builder.Services.AddOptions<MicrosoftIdentityOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .Configure<IClaimsAPI>((options, claimsApi) =>
                {
                    options.Events = new()
                    {
                        OnTokenValidated = context =>
                        {
                            context.Principal = claimsApi.Transform(context.Principal);
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
                    };
                });
```

Comment: This is pretty succinct! I need to sit down and read through all the options documentation, it seems to be much more powerful than i expected. I ended up wrapping all of this into a oneliner `AddClaimsAPI() anyway, because im building a companion nuget package for the api for my coworkers to get the integration.  Thanks for the extra understanding!